# errorCopyingDatabase from Assets folder to memory

Tags: android, sqlite, database-connection

I'm following this link to open connection to Database. However when I try to open it, it throws an exception saying errorCopyingDatabase. My database size is around 20MB. Is it due to the size that it's not getting copied from Assets folder to memory or some other issue. I'm sure my code is fine and I've also double checked all the paths (everything seems to be fine). I get the following exception:

```
12-14 04:44:45.471: E/AndroidRuntime(512): java.lang.Error: ErrorCopyingDataBase
12-14 04:44:45.471: E/AndroidRuntime(512):  at com.bondsms.db.DBHelper.createDataBase(DBHelper.java:42)
12-14 04:44:45.471: E/AndroidRuntime(512):  at com.bondsms.db.DBAdapter.createDatabase(DBAdapter.java:37)
12-14 04:44:45.471: E/AndroidRuntime(512):  at com.bondsms.BSGroupsActivity.loadAllGroupsFromDB(BSGroupsActivity.java:98)
12-14 04:44:45.471: E/AndroidRuntime(512):  at com.bondsms.BSGroupsActivity.onCreate(BSGroupsActivity.java:55)
12-14 04:44:45.471: E/AndroidRuntime(512):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-14 04:44:45.471: E/AndroidRuntime(512):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-14 04:44:45.471: E/AndroidRuntime(512):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-14 04:44:45.471: E/AndroidRuntime(512):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-14 04:44:45.471: E/AndroidRuntime(512):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-14 04:44:45.471: E/AndroidRuntime(512):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-14 04:44:45.471: E/AndroidRuntime(512):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-14 04:44:45.471: E/AndroidRuntime(512):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-14 04:44:45.471: E/AndroidRuntime(512):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 04:44:45.471: E/AndroidRuntime(512):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-14 04:44:45.471: E/AndroidRuntime(512):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-14 04:44:45.471: E/AndroidRuntime(512):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-14 04:44:45.471: E/AndroidRuntime(512):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have try a lot of time to copying database from asset, and this's my class to copy, it's works fine for me, you could use it, maybe it help (remember to change DB_PATH = "/data/data/[your package]/databases/". And DB_NAME = your data name in asset).

```
 public class DatabaseController extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.hanoifood/databases/";

    private static final String DB_NAME = "HanoiFood.sqlite";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
     * access to the application assets and resources.
     * 
     * @param context
     */
    public DatabaseController(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
        try {
            createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
     * database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
            myDataBase = getWritableDatabase();
        } else {
            myDataBase = getWritableDatabase();
            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
     * time you open the application.
     * 
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            // database does't exist yet.

        }

        if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
     * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
     * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    }

    public Cursor query(String table, String[] columns, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having,
            String orderBy) {
        myDataBase = getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.query(table, columns, selection,
                selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    public long insert(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values) {
        long insertRet = myDataBase.insert(table, nullColumnHack, values);
        if (insertRet == -1) {
            Log.d("DungHV", "Insert db error");
        }
        return insertRet;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

In your Activity simple call:

```
DatabaseContrller mdb = new DatabaseController(getApplicationContext());
```